# Tailwind not styling my NextJs project in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, css, ubuntu, next.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS is not styling my project at all in Ubuntu 20.04.

The project works fine in windows but in Ubuntu somehow it is not styling at all.

[image]

1. globals.css
   [image]
2. _app.js
   [image]
3. tailwind.config.js
   [image]

P.S all other Tailwind projects working fine in Ubuntu (i.e New tailwind projects are working fine).

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?  Can you share your code (or at least the portion that is importing the tailwind files?)

Comment: No there is no error in console, I'll update my question and post screenshot on it please wait a bit. thanks

Comment: I found out that the issue is related to jit in tailwind css...It is not working in ubuntu somehow

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the Components folder. It was started with capital 'C', while it should be lowercase.

Windows is case insensitive that's why the problem was not occurring on the windows while Linux is case sensitive so it was not working properly.

For more detail refer : [this issue on github](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4414)